# Button click event is not fired

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Asp button click does not fire. I wrote Response.Write("404.aspx"); in to button click event in codebehind. But it does not fire. Here is the page with a fire problem button:
[please click here](http://www.webyuk.com/siltest.aspx)

thanks.

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void bntTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("404.aspx");
}
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("404.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code-behind as well as source code ?

Comment: i wrote code behind. there are no code except these. i think problem is about css or .js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because your submit button is not inside the `form` tag so it won't be able to post the submitted data and the same time, the click event will not fire as the page does not post, you can see below:

[image: form]

EDIT:

You have added a nested `form` tag that you can not because `form` tag can not be nested within another form tag. So just remove the nested form tag and it will work.

Try to restructure your project using these guidelines:

- Only add `form` elements to aspx pages
- Add main content to `MasterPage` from pages
- Add any content that needs to be nested within a `form` to a `UserControl` that is placed within a page.

Comment: i have only one form tag. and this form tag is in masterpage. and this form tag covers contentplace holder. so it must cover this siltest.aspx. how can i fix this? thanks

Comment: i see form tag covers ContentPlaceHolder object in visual studio. but in runtime, you are right. it does not cover ContentPlaceHolder. this is weird. by the way. i have another ContentPlaceHolder in master page in head tag. does it cause this problem?

Comment: can you check. i have post masterpage and child page (testsil.aspx) to here: http://pastebin.com/dC2WExbY

Comment: @selcuksel Ok.. So I have found an issue..what you did is: you have added one another nested `form` tag that you can not because `form` tab can not be nested within another `form` tag. So just remove the nested `form` tag and it will work.